# Updating columns in table with values from another table and getting unexpected NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running a hefty update query with multiple CTEs to update a number of columns (50+) in table "A" with values from columns in table "B". When the query finishes, all of the columns in table A have successfully been updated except for two columns that contain large amounts of NULL values (I would say 75% NULL values). This is completely unexpected because **neither of the two columns in table A or table B contain any NULL values**.

Simplified example code (**only showing the final CTE with the two columns in question**):

```
    WITH B AS
    (SELECT T.position
     ,CASE WHEN CTE1.full_name = '' THEN CTE2._name 
     ELSE CTE1.full_name 
     END AS Name
     ,CASE WHEN CTE1.emp_id = '' THEN CTE2.emp_id 
     ELSE CTE1.emp_id 
     END AS Id
     FROM T
     LEFT JOIN CTE1
     ON T.code = CTE1.code
     LEFT JOIN CTE2
     ON T.code = CTE2.code
    )

    UPDATE A
    SET A.Name = B.Name, A.Id = B.Id
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.code = B.code
```

This question is a shot in the dark as I know this simplified code might be too general to draw any conclusions. If anyone does have any prior experience with unexpected NULL values in the above scenario, any trouble shooting tips would be appreciated as I am not perfectly sure where to start looking.

Comment: Tip : if possible, use `INNER JOIN`s instead of `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: Do CTE1 and CTE2 have null values? As general advice, if you're having issues with this sort of thing, it might be an idea to step through each part of the query and see what is happening. Though this is almost certainly the result of a left join not working the way you thought it would, so I'd start with looking there.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. CTE1 does contain NULL values but CTE2 does not. And now that I come to think of it I am not sure why I wrote CASE WHEN CTE1.emp_id = '"" instead of  CASE WHEN CTE1.emp_id IS NULL in my final CTE. Could this be the reason for the NULL values? Am not in front of my computer to check until tomorrow

Comment: It's either that or there are cases where "T" has values that are not in "CTE1" and "CTE2" (which would result in NULL regardless of whether you rewrite it). But yes, if for example CTE.full_name is NULL then it will default to using that value anyway with how the case expression is currently written.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot (and to permanently stop using UPDATE … FROM ) add another CTE, like this:

```
 WITH B AS
    (SELECT T.position
     ,CASE WHEN CTE1.full_name = '' THEN CTE2._name 
     ELSE CTE1.full_name 
     END AS Name
     ,CASE WHEN CTE1.emp_id = '' THEN CTE2.emp_id 
     ELSE CTE1.emp_id 
     END AS Id
     FROM T
     LEFT JOIN CTE1
     ON T.code = CTE1.code
     LEFT JOIN CTE2
     ON T.code = CTE2.code
    ), C as
    (
      select a.Name a_name, b.Name b_name, a.ID a_id, b.ID b_id
      FROM A
      LEFT JOIN B
      ON A.code = B.code
    )
    select * from c
    --update C set a_name = b_name, a_id = b_id
```

Examine the results, troubleshoot, then switch to an UPDATE.

Comment: I tried to implement this but 1) I am getting the error "View or function 'C' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables."; 2) With 50+ columns to update this seems like an overly large amount of extra typing just to bypass "UPDATE... FROM" (since you have to specify the column names in the new CTE); 3) What would be the benefit of bypassing "UPDATE... FROM"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a left join from A to B. That left join means that if there is no matching B row for a table A row, then all the values in B will be null. This is almost certainly where your null values are coming from.

You could do an inner join, so that you only update rows in table A that have matching B rows. This would stop you getting null values, but may not be what you need - some Table A rows will not be updated at all.

If you need to put some default value into A if there is no B row, then you need to still do a left join, but change your set command to something like

```
SET A.Name = COALESCE(B.Name, "defaultvalue")
```

If you think there should be a matching row for every Table A row, then you need to debug your CTEs and find out which one is not returning the values you expect.